# vba - Parse xml Google Contacts v3

Tags: xml, ms-access, vba

i'm not able to parse to following xml string with my vba-code:

```
Dim oXml As MSXML2.DOMDocument60
Set oXml = New MSXML2.DOMDocument60


Dim xmlstr As String: xmlstr = XmlResponse
 oXml.loadXML xmlstr

Dim oSeqNodes, oSeqNode As IXMLDOMNode
Set oSeqNodes = oXml.selectNodes("//feed/entry")


If oSeqNodes.Length = 0 Then
   'show some message nix da
   GetGoogleContactsGroupBySearchString = "parsing_error"
Else
    For Each oSeqNode In oSeqNodes
         'Debug.Print oSeqNode.selectSingleNode("id").Text
         'Debug.Print oSeqNode.selectSingleNode("title").Text

         If oSeqNode.selectSingleNode("title").Text = "System Group: My Contacts" Then
         'If oSeqNode.selectSingleNode("title").Text = SearchStr Then
            GetGoogleContactsGroupBySearchString = oSeqNode.selectSingleNode("id").Text
            Exit For
         End If
    Next
End If
End Function
```

If the XML item contains objects

```
<feed xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom' xmlns:gd='http://schemas.google.com/g/2005' xmlns:batch='http://schemas.google.com/gdata/batch' xmlns:gContact='http://schemas.google.com/contact/2008' xmlns:openSearch='http://a9.com/-/spec/opensearch/1.1/' gd:etag='&quot;EFsQTwpDASlgJns6UA..&quot;'> ... </feed>
```

it does NOT WORK, else if it looks like `<feed> .... </feed>` it works.

Comment: Is there XML missing? I am not sure how you are expecting a result from //feed/entry from the above.

Comment: If you do a GET request to https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/username%40gmail.com/full you get the full XML-File or you can see it here: [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1R7AcRLGsqejbFMK3Z_fQBsndf3s7mNrb/view?usp=sharing)

if the xml file looks like this:
<feed><entry>blablabal</entry><entry>blablabal</entry></feed> it works, but if it look like this <feed xmlns='blabla'><entry etag='asfadsf'>blablaa</entry></feed> it fails

Comment: so with that link you sent: what wouldbe an example failing xpath please?

Comment: there is no error, it does not find the Node "//feed/entry" when <feed xmlns='blabla'><entry etag='asfadsf'>blablaa</entry></feed> is set. A xml string looks like this <feed><entry>blablabal</entry><entry>blablabal</entry></feed> find the node